# Transfer funds to inherited smart contracts

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.6.x, solidity-0.7.x

How would I make this work - the balanceOf[Pool, System + Cube] doesn't seem to work ;-;

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPLv2
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "./Pool.sol";
import "./Cube.sol";

contract System is Cube, Pool{

    // Variables.
    address public referer;
    bool internal registered = false;
    mapping(address => bool) public isRegistered;
    mapping(address => uint256) internal balanceOf;

    constructor() public {
        address adminWallet = msg.sender;
    }

    // Checks to see if msg.sender is registered.
    function viewRegister() public view returns(bool _isRegistered) {
        _isRegistered = isRegistered[msg.sender];
        return _isRegistered;
    } 
    
    // Receives register payment. *Needs payments to be distributed to pool, cube and admin wallet!
    function initalRegisterPayment(uint256 defaultAmount) payable public returns(bool success) {
        require(isRegistered[msg.sender] = false, "You are already registered!");
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= 0.13 ether, "You are already registered!");

        defaultAmount = 0.13 ether;

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= defaultAmount;
        
        balanceOf[System] -= 0.03 ether;
        balanceOf[adminWallet] += 0.03 ether;
        
        balanceOf[System] -= 0.05 ether;
        balanceOf[Pool] += 0.05 ether;
        
        balanceOf[System] -= 0.05 ether;
        balanceOf[Cube] += 0.05 ether;
        
        return true;
    }
    
    function register(address _newAddress) public {
        require(isRegistered = false, "You are already registered!");
    }
}
```

The code for each inherited contract are like this one:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPLv2
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Pool {
    
    fallback() payable external {}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use inheritance? `contract System is Cube, Pool` I suggest you just keep track of payments using just the addresses, without inheritance. That will be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding inheritance.

Inheritance rolls up the inherited *code* and incorporates it into the child contract. So, your `System` has a `payable` fallback function because it inherited the method.

What you probably want instead is two separate contracts. Here is a very simple example to help you refactor.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

contract System {
    
    Pool pool;
    
    constructor () public {
        pool = new Pool(); // pool needs to be instantiated. One way is to create it when the System is deployed
    }
    
    function payMe() public payable {
        address(pool).transfer(msg.value); // send money to the Pool
    }
}

contract Pool {
    
    fallback () external payable { // receive money
        
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sweet, thank you :) Just wondering what the  Pool pool  does?

Comment: Can you please review [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90159/16043). The results are quite staggering IMO. Could this be a potential issue in the ecosystem, or did I get something wrong? Thanks.