# What is the gas limit for a fallback function called when the method does not exist?

Tags: solidity, gas-limit, fallback-function

According to the docs a non matching function identifier will trigger the fallback function. So what happens if someone calls my contract with "thisMethodDoesntExist()", would the fallback have a limit of 2300 like when it is triggered with `send` / `transfer`, or will it have gas from by the calling method like `.call.value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly no, and [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.12/contracts.html#fallback-function) is indeed not even clear about this.

So here is a short test for printing the gas remaining at the beginning of the fallback function:

**Solidity Contract:**

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

interface Interface0 {
    function thisMethodDoesntExist() external;
}

contract Contract1 {
    // note that prior to solidity 0.6.0, you need to replace `fallback` with `function`
    fallback() external payable {
        string memory message;
        uint256 x = gasleft();
        while (x > 0) {
            message = string(abi.encodePacked(uint8(x % 10 + 48), message));
            x /= 10;
        }
        revert(message);
    }
}

contract Contract2 {
    function test(Interface0 contract1) external {
        contract1.thisMethodDoesntExist();
    }
}
```

**Truffle 5.x Test:**

```
const Contract1 = artifacts.require("Contract1");
const Contract2 = artifacts.require("Contract2");

contract("test", (accounts) => {
    it("test", async () => {
        contract1 = await Contract1.new();
        contract2 = await Contract2.new();
        try {
            await contract2.test(contract1.address);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

The printout of this test is:

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert 9328773 -- Reason given: 9328773
```

Comment: I don't see how this would be a big problem. If I call a method which doesn't exist the fallback is called instead with the original gas stipend. Obviously this is probably not what  the user intended, but I don't see any better alternative either - it's good to have some way to catch arbitrary (wrong) function calls.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: The conclusions are correct, gas stipend is enforced by the caller.

Comment: @Ismael: Thank you for the feedback! Coming to think about this again, maybe it's not that much of a surprise. The 2300 stipend is designated to protect your own contract from reentrancy attacks when you execute `transfer` or `send` from a function in that contract, not when you execute some non-existing function. In other words, you should know what you're doing, and executing `transfer` or `send` goes under the category of knowing what you're doing (while executing some non-existing function doesn't).